# Accessing class fields from arrayList index?

Tags: java, class, variables, arraylist

I need to access lots of very similar objects and everything within them. So far, I have three classes:

"Piece" - Does nothing so far, but is subclassed by LcPawn.

"LcPawn" - This has one line of code, '''public static int ID;''' which is supposed to hold a different number for each instance of the LcPawn.

"Main" - The code in question is as follows:

```
public static ArrayList<LcPawn> LcPawns = new ArrayList<LcPawn>(256);
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i ++) {
    LcPawns.add(i, new LcPawn());
}
for (int i = 0; i < LcPawns.size(); i ++) {
    LcPawns.get(i).ID = i; 
}
for (int i = 0; i < LcPawns.size(); i ++) {
    System.out.println(LcPawns.get(i).ID);
}
```

However, nothing comes up on the console. The separate loops are so I can make sure this works without having to reset all the objects over and over again. This is as much as i know.

Comment: Can you explain what the keyword `static` means?

Comment: `This has one line of code, '''public static int ID;''' which is supposed to hold a different number for each instance of the LcPawn` - this is not how static variables work.  An Object with a static variable will be limited to one instance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some things to note:

Your `LcPawn` class has a variable `public static int ID;` which you say should have a different value for each instance. In Java, the keyword `static` in this context does the opposite of that, it declares a "class variable", instead of an "instance variable". To provide one instance of `ID` for each instance of `LcPawn`, just remove `static` here and that should be fine.

Second, a convention worth sticking to is to make all fields `private`, while providing "getters and setters". For example, instead of declaring a class as follows:

```
public class MyClass {
    public int value;
}
```

instead declare it as:

```
public class MyClass {
    private int value;

    public void setValue(int value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public int getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

This has several advantages:

- You can add business logic to the functions, e.g. perhaps you want to forbid negative numbers in the `value` field. You can add a line: `if (value < 0) throw new NegativeNumberException();`
- You can change implementation without changing the rest of your code. Perhaps you want to get your value from the internet, or you use a library that wants to lazy-load your variable. This is only possible with a method call, and cannot be done by a raw variable.
- Many popular libraries expect classes to be in this format (e.g. Jackson Databind, and Spring).

You should also follow standard Java capitalization rules:

- field names and methods are written `likeThis` and `likeThis()`
- class names are written `LikeThis`
- constants are written `LIKE_THIS`

---

With that in mind, here is how I would write your code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<LcPawn> pawns = new ArrayList<>(256);  // more generic type and type parameter omitted for brevity

    for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
        pawns.add(new LcPawn());  // no need to specify an index, it gets added to the end by default
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < pawns.size(); i++) {
        pawns.get(i).setId(i);  // using setter method
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < pawns.size(); i++) {
        System.out.println(pawns.get(i).getId());  // using getter method
    }
}
```

However, this can be compacted into one single `for` loop:

```
List<LcPawn> pawns = new ArrayList<>(256);
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    LcPawn pawn = new LcPawn();
    pawn.setId(i);
    System.out.println(pawn.getId());
    pawns.add(pawn);
}
```

Or, with Java 8 streams:

```
IntStream.range(0, 256)  // generate a stream of integers from 0-255
    .map(i -> {  // map each integer to a pawn with that integer as its id
        LcPawn pawn = new LcPawn();
        pawn.setId(i);
        return pawn;
    })
    .forEach(System.out::println);  // print all of them, using a "method reference"
```

Comment: I think that It would be better to pass the id as a constructor parameter for the LcPawn class in order to get rid of the second for loop